# Form inserting empty data to database

Tags: php, mysql

Whenever I submit the form with empty input, it sends the empty input to my database. The form was working fine until after I used the htmlentities() for its functionality.

I used the gettype() function to return what's in the inserted variable and it returns "string", but when I checked the code from the browser, I could not see anything in the table.

```
This is the code snippet and the form processing code

<?php
$errors = [];
$missing = [];

if(isset($_POST['sendFirm']) ){

$expected = array('firmName','country','state','email','phoneNumber');
$required = array('firmName','country','state','phoneNumber');

<?php

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

        if(is_array($value)){
            $value = $value;
            }else{
            $value = trim($value);
            }

        if(empty($value) && in_array($key, $required)){
        $missing[] = $key;
        $$key = '';
        }elseif(in_array($key, $expected)){
        $$key = "$value";
        }
}

?>
}



?>
<?php 
        if($errors || $missing){
     ?>
     <p>Please fix the following items</p>
    <?php } ?>
<form method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">
<div class="form-group">
<label>Compnay Name
<?php if($missing && in_array('firmName', $missing)) { ?>
    <span class="text-danger">Please enter firm name</span>
<?php } ?>
</label>
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="firmName" id="firmName" placeholder="Company Name"
<?php
if($errors || $missing){
    print 'value="' . htmlentities($firmName) . '"';
}
>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" 
name="sendFirm">Submit</button>
</form>
?>
>


<?php


if(isset($_POST['sendFirm'])){
    try {
    $connectToFirms = new 
PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=firms','root','2332');
    $connectToFirms->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, 
PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $prepInsertion = $connectToFirms->prepare('INSERT INTO contractors 
VALUES (null,?,?,?,?,?)');

    $prepInsertion->execute(array($firmName, $country, $state, $email, 
$phoneNumber));

}catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "An error occure: " . $e->getMessage();
}
}


?>
```

The form is expected to insert inputs into the database only if the input is not empty and is also in the $expected[];

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. First of all: $_POST['sendFirm'] is never set in your script.  Please correct/complete the shown code :-) Otherwise we can only guess.

Comment: There is nothing stopping the `INSERT` code from happening when you POST the form. If you `POST` an empty form, your code creates empty vars and does the `INSERT` with them.

Comment: Also, you are not properly closing your `<?php` tag around the `htmlentities` call. Your `?>` isn't until after the `</form>` tag. That code must be throwing an error.

Comment: Okay I'll do that and see if the problem will go away. Appreciate your respond and help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Don't insert data

I would stop the whole data insertion, if the expected input is not given. I would also send the input data one by one to PHP, so you have a better overview over your code. Good overview = less errors ;)

Try it this way:

```php
<?php

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST") {

    $firmname = htmlentities($_POST["firmName"], ENT_QUOTES);

    $country = htmlentities($_POST["country"], ENT_QUOTES);

    $state = htmlentities($_POST["state"], ENT_QUOTES);

    $pn = htmlentities($_POST["phoneNumber"], ENT_QUOTES);

// LET'S START THE VALIDATION

    // if the required fields are not empty, insert data
    if (!empty($firmname) && !empty($country) && !empty(state) && !empty($pn)) {

        // insert data

    } else { // else stop insertion and return error message

        // return error message

    }
} else {
    // redirect...
}
```

I hope, i understood your question correctly and could help.

Comment: Okay I'll do that. However, I've never used htmlentities() with second argument so I'm not sure what the second argument does :).

Comment: PHP Doc for [htmlentities](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

Comment: the ```ENT_QUOTES``` argument basically allows '-single & "-double-quotes. Otherwise they would be removed out of your string because of the ```htmlentities()``` function.

Comment: I used your validation idea and it worked. Appreciate it.

Comment: I‘m happy that i could help you.